# How to determine Dunn Index using clValid package in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to replicate the results of a journal paper, where the authors have proposed a clustering algorithm and have computed the Dunn index for the resulting cluster using the clValid in R. I was able to replicate the cluster. However, I am unable to get the Dunn index.

I have the adjacency matrix (adj) as shown below:

```
adj <-matrix(c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
                 1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,
                   1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,
                   1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,
                   0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
                   1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,
                   0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,
                   1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,
                   1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,
                   0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
                   0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,
                   0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,
                   1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,
                   0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0),
          nrow=34, # number of rows
          ncol=34, 
          byrow = TRUE)
```

The resulting cluster membership as

```
membership <- c(1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  1,  3,  3,  1,  1,  1,  1, 3,  3,  2,  1,  3,  1,  3,  1,  3,  3,  1,  1,  3,  3,  1,  3,  3,  1, 3,  3)
```

I used the following code to compute the Dunn index:

```
dist_dunn <- dist(adj, method = "euclidean") 
dunn_value <- dunn(distance = dist_dunn, clusters = membership)  
dunn_value
```

The resulting output is `0.2132`. However, the actual output reported in the journal paper is `0.111`. Can someone help me with this and let me know where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can confirm a value of `0.2132007` based on the data you provide and a euclidean distance measure. You can define different inter/intra-cluster distances, anddepending on the definition you get different Dunn indices. Obviously we don't know how the authors of the paper you mention have defined the Dunn index. Perhaps take a look at any supplementary material; it also would've helped if you had provided the reference to the paper in question.